# AdMob is only shows test ads

Tags: android, admob

AdMob only shows test ads, this is the code on the Activity:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-869XXXXXXXXXXX50/209XXXXX42"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/anuncio2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/anuncio1"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/anuncio1">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

This Java code enable the ads:

```
MobileAds.initialize(this,"ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX~XXXXXXXXXX");
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            for(int id: Arrays.asList(R.id.anuncio1,R.id.anuncio2))((AdView)findViewById(id)).loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        }
    });
```

This is my AndroidMainfest.xml: https://pastebin.com/LgMBmYNW

And this my build.gradle for the Module app: https://pastebin.com/gQUiYVrj

Regards.

Comment: my vague idea would be to ask: are you still using a test key?

Comment: My user-id is ca-app-pub-869XXXXXXXXXX250~53XXXXXX40